# Gift Wrapping Algorithm in Python never terminating

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry

I've been trying to implement the gift wrapping algorithm in Python, I currently have the following code:

```
def createIslandPolygon(particleCoords):

    startPoint = min(particleCoords.iteritems(),key = lambda x: x[1][1])[1]

    check = 1

    islandPolygon = []

    particleList = []

    for key in particleCoords:

        particleList.append(particleCoords[key])

    currentPoint = startPoint

    while(currentPoint != startPoint or check == 1):

        islandPolygon.append(currentPoint)

        check = 0

        angleDict = {}
        angleList = []

        for point in particleList:

            if point != currentPoint:

                angleDict[(angleBetweenTwoPoints(currentPoint, point))] = point
                angleList.append(angleBetweenTwoPoints(currentPoint, point))

        smallestAngle = min(angleList)

        currentPoint = angleDict[smallestAngle]

    return islandPolygon
```

and for calculating the polar coordinates:

```
def angleBetweenTwoPoints(p1, p2):

    p3 = (p1[0], p1[1] + 2)

    a = (p1[0] - p2[0], p1[1] - p2[1])
    b = (p1[0] - p3[0], p1[1] - p3[1])

    theta = ((a[0]*b[0]) + (a[1]*b[1]))
    theta = theta / (sqrt((a[0]*a[0]) + (a[1]*a[1])) * sqrt((b[0]*b[0]) + (b[1]*b[1])))
    theta = math.acos(theta)

    return theta
```

The problem is that the code never seems to leave the while loop, and I'm not sure why. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

(yeah, the codes pretty shoddy, I just threw it together quickly)

Edit: Printing out the coordinates seems to show them jumping between just two coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm you need to do this:

```
   pointOnHull = leftmost point in S
   i = 0
   repeat
      P[i] = pointOnHull
      endpoint = S[0]         // initial endpoint for a candidate edge on the hull
      for j from 1 to |S|-1
         if (endpoint == pointOnHull) or (S[j] is on left of line from P[i] to endpoint)
            endpoint = S[j]   // found greater left turn, update endpoint
      i = i+1
      pointOnHull = endpoint
   until endpoint == P[0]      // wrapped around to first hull point
```

You have this correct:

```
   pointOnHull = leftmost point in S
```

And this:

```
  P[i] = pointOnHull
```

But here's the part I'm not sure about:

```
  (S[j] is on left of line from P[i] to endpoint)
```

Instead you find the *smallest* angle out of all the angles it makes with all other points. But according to wikipedia what you want is the *leftmost* angle out of all the angles it makes with all other points. I have some code for working with angles:

```
def normalizeangle(radians):
    return divmod(radians, math.pi*2)[1]



def arclength(radians1, radians2 = 0):
    radians1, radians2 = normalizeangle(radians1), normalizeangle(radians2)
    return min(normalizeangle(radians1 - radians2), normalizeangle(radians2 - radians1))



def arcdir(radians1, radians2 = 0):
    radians1, radians2 = normalizeangle(radians1), normalizeangle(radians2)
    return cmp(normalizeangle(radians1 - radians2), normalizeangle(radians2 - radians1))
```

`arcdir` will tell you if an angle is on the left or on the right of another, so you can use it to see if an angle is more left and so should be used.

If you move along the points always picking the leftmost angle to the next point, you'll go around the perimeter of your polygon and reach the beginning again (since you picked the leftmost point, you know it has to be on the perimeter and will be reached again)

Comment: Ah, I understand now why it's jumping between two points. I'm trying to implement your solution now, one thing I'm not sure about though, you say to compare 2 angles, do you just mean that I should find which is the leftmost of all of them and use that? So go through angleList comparing all the angles until I get the leftmost and use that?

Comment: As the wikipedia pseudocode does, you can keep one angle (the leftmost so far) in memory and compare against that. BTW, make sure the case of going from exactly downwards to exactly upwards (a pi radians turn) is handled as being considered the most leftmost angle, and going from exactly upwards to exactly downwards is handled correctly similarly - or else your algorithm might randomly fail on perfectly straight vertical edges that are made of more than two points.